# Trying to ID a certain Superhero game

Tags: product-identification

I'm trying to remember a game I played with a GM a long time ago, I remember a few things about the game but other than those things, my mind is a blur.

The things I remember are:

- The Game prominently featured superheroes of some kind
- Combat and skill checks were done based on power levels and were completed by rolling a 1d100 and consulting a table
- Powers had levels based on proficiency, from Poor all the way to.. I think one was Amazing?
- Covered a wide variety of powers, from Shadow walking to lightning manipulation.

Other than that I can't really think of anything in particular that would reflect what game it was. I'm curious because I had a lot of fun, the name just escapes me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While your outline is sparse on detail, I'd suggest that it sounds like Marvel Superheroes - and later Marvel Superheroes Advanced Set, which used the FASERIP system. You had Attributes rated on a scale with names like Feeble, Typical through to Unearthly and beyond. Getting anything done involved rolling 1d100, comparing against your Attributes or Powers, and then seeing whether you got a good enough result on the colourful results table.

You can now find many resources for the game online - like [ClassicMarvelForever.com](http://ClassicMarvelForever.com) - and various open iterations of the game mechanics reworked into new systems - rather like the whole Old School Renaissance movement for early D&D editions.

Comment: The game's *Ultimate Powers Book* remains one of the best general-purpose superhero game resources ever in its attempt to quantify *every superpower ever*, but, wow, does it make for some *weird* random characters.

Comment: Wait... they called their game mechanics system "face-rip"?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Pronounce like "phase" or "faze", with a *zzz* sound.

Comment: Wow man you hit the nail on the head with this answer. What a great site, I wish I knew it existed, but now I'm glad I do!